# Mail Chimp Extension Issue

Tags: magento2

I have tried to install Mailchimp Ext. a lot of times in magento 2 trying the below Ext. https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html & https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2 but get the same bellow error, please advice, I am only need to make sync between the subscriber on my magento 2 website and my mailchimp list.

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Fieldset\Hint
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Fieldset\Hint does not exist
```

Comment: Are you cloning or unzipping this right into `app/code`, or are you installing this via composer?

Comment: I have installed it app/code and its fixed now, but when trying to open Mailchimp store, I get the below error                                                                                                             1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Exception): Table "mailchimp_stores" does not exist

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Exception): Table "mailchimp_stores" does not exist
<pre>#1 Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\Data->loadStores() called at [vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Controller/Adminhtml/Stores/Index.php:21]